# $.ajax using JsonResult - Returns "toJSON - function (key) { return this.valueOf(); }"

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is what I have:

### Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult GetNumbers(int id)
  {
      List<int> privIDs = new List<int>();
      //My Numbers!                
      privIDs.Add(2);
      privIDs.Add(3);
      return Json(privIDs);
  }
```

### Javascript

```
    var id = 1;
    url = "/Home/GetNumbers/";
    var getData = {
        'Id': id
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: getData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result, function () {
                $.each(this, function (index, data) {
                    alert(index + " - " + data);
                });
            });
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert("fail");
        }
    });
```

### The Result

Two alert boxes both containing:

```
toJSON - function (key) { return this.valueOf(); }
```

### The Question

Where are my numbers? (2 & 3 in this example...)

### EDIT

I swear I did this before.  But this is what i was after..

```
                    success: function (result) {
                        $.each(result, function (index, value) {
                            alert(index + ': ' + value);
                        });
                    },
```

Comment: @blank  you are doing it wrong  don't just print data directly , use firebug net panel json tab and see how the data is coming , it might be data.something or data[].something...check the object structure...

Comment: @blank , please check whats there in data  through firebug..net panel

Comment: @gov Yea. It looks right in there... So what if I want to print it?  How do I access it?  It says 0  2 and 1  3.. Response is [2,3].

Comment: access the same way it shows in firebug .json tab....see my answer

Comment: @blank that is a list which is converted automatically to object notation , so your values will be result.privIDs[0] , result.privIDs[1] like that

Comment: Yea I figured it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove your code and just try this , just for testing , if it works just write a loop statement

```
success: function (result) {
            // loop through this
            result.privIDs[0]
        },
```

Comment: blank , do you have firebug net panel , in that there is option call json , see the object structure and access exactly like that....

Comment: @blank i got it now , your list is not an object , it just integers that is why it is just send back as plain array , as i always send them as array of objects i started trying like that...sorry